# Overwriting function in class from another class(coffescript/javascript)

Tags: javascript, class, function, coffeescript, overwrite

Hi guys I have some issue at work that I can't handle by myself. Everything is written in coffescript but of course if someone want to help me by using JS, I don't mind, i appreciate all help :)
So let's get to it.

I'm trainee and because of my weird leader I'm forced to overwrite some function in class. So let's say I have class MyParentClass and it contains:

```
class @MyParentClass
  firstFunction: (var) ->
    imp
  secondFunction: (var)->
    doest matter really
```

So I have 2 functions in my class, but I would like only to "overwrite" first one. So my class is being used in another class:

```
class @ImUsingParentClass
  someFunction: ->
    new MyParentClass(some variables)
```

And what's more another class extends and using this class

```
class @ImSoLonely extends ImUsingParentClass
```

So it's almost over :)
I have to change `firstFunction` from `MyParentClass` in `ImSoLonely`.

I was reading some stuff about creating `MyParentClass` as abstract one (it's working in coffescript) but still I have no idea how to use it in `ImSoLonely`, how to execute another class(function?) that overwrites `firstFunction`. 
Much thanks in advance!!!!! 
And if you can't read this code please let me now and I'll try to convert it into javascript one. 
Sorry for my bad English but I hope it's understandable.

Comment: You need to change `MyParentClass#firstFunction` only when it comes from `ImSoLonely#someFunction`?

Comment: yeah ImSoLonely execudes function thats using class ImUsingParentClass, and function in ImUsingParentClass is using functions from MyParentClass

Comment: Why not subclass `MyParentClass` to provide an override for `firstFunction` and then `ImSoLonely#someFunction` can override `ImUsingParentClass#someFunction` to use your new subclass instead of `MyParentClass`?

Comment: Thank you very much this totally worked. Subclass extends main one and overwriting firstFunction :) thank you again